# Can't install pip version 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip

```
c:\Python-3.4.8\PCbuild>python get-pip.py

DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP 429).
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip<19.2
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<19.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<19.2
```

Comment: Did you read the deprecation message? Why not upgrade to a newer Python?

Comment: Same as @Dennis here why use such an ancient version of python when you can use python 3.7 or newer

Answer (score 0):

Runs in cmd
py -m pip install --upgrade pip